# How to create a single node AKS cluster using a 1-year reserved instance?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, instance, reserved

As the title says, I can't figure out how you're supposed to do this.  The pricing calculator allows for it, so I'm assuming it's possible.

I've tried:

1) Creating a new cluster

2) Creating a vm and adding it to an existing cluster, then deleting the initial node (Tried with and without the scaleset option)

For #1, I see no options to add a reserved instance during cluster initialization.  For #2, I see no options to add an existing vm to an existing aks cluster.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After you buy an Azure Reserved Virtual Machine Instance, the reservation  discount is automatically applied to virtual machines that match the attributes and quantity of the reservation. A reservation covers the compute costs of your virtual machines. [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-vm-reservation-charges)

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-understand-vm-reservation-charges#instance-size-flexibility-setting) you can see that this also applies to AKS.

In other words, you buy a reserved instance and after you create your AKS cluster selecting instances with the same size, the discount will be automatically applied.

> A reservation discount applies to the base VMs that you purchase from the Azure Marketplace.

By Marketplace you can also read AKS.

Comment: So an "Azure Reserved Virtual Machine Instance" is not a VM at all, is it?  From what you're saying, it's a voucher that covers X amount of usage for a given VM type.  That makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Exactly, unfortunately interface isn't very clear about that. Everyone expects something different since on other platforms is different.